# Get li Element Text When Click on that Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code. When I click on any `li` element then the first alert it shows its value, then show its parent then again that parent and so on. I just want to show the text of the clicked `li` element. How can I do that?

```js
$('#container li').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul class="xyz">
    <li>Grand Parent 1</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="xyz">
        <li>Parent 1</li>
        <li>Parent 2
          <ul class="xyz">
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
            <li>Child 4</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Parent 3</li>
        <li>Parent 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: now just check it

Comment: @Lount 
Now I think U can do it

Comment: @AminMemariani Bad dup, all the answers are more or less exactly what OP has already tried ...

Comment: No this is not.. In that case there is only on <ul> element

Comment: @AliAbbas You did not describe your question well. Be thankful to Rory McCrossan

Comment: @AliAbbas at least accept the answer Rory gave you. That way you can thank him for the help he provided to you.

Answer (score 4):

Your first issue is that you need to stop the proprgation of the event from the clicked `li` to the parent `li` elements. You can call `stopPropagation` on the passed event handler to do that.

Secondly, I assume you only want to retrieve the child text value of the `li`, not the text of it's descendants, in which case you would need to use `contents()[0]` to access it. Try this:

```js
$('#container li').on('click', function(e) {  
  e.stopPropagation();
  var text = $(this).contents()[0].nodeValue.trim();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <ul class="xyz">
    <li>Grand Parent 1</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="xyz">
        <li>Parent 1</li>
        <li>
          Parent 2
          <ul class="xyz">
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
            <li>Child 4</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Parent 3</li>
        <li>Parent 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```